# Passing a value from a child component to another one (same level) without waiting for parent status update

Tags: reactjs

I do not have a lot of experience with React so here it goes.
    I am trying to build a simple website, with multi language support.
    For this, I have the parent component (App), with 2 child components (LanguageSelector and Menu).
    What I want to achieve: when I select the language from the LanguageSelector component, the text existing in the Menu component is updated depending on the language selected.

### What is happening?

1. I open the web site, the Menu component is filled with the text defined in the default language
2. When I change the language, the parent component (App) receives the new language from the child
3. The Menu child is updated with the previous language instead of the selectedLanguage because the parent component is only updated when all the child are updated.

### What I would like to know:

1. What am I doing wrong?
2. Is this the global right way to do this?
3. How can I pass the selected language from the LanguageSelector child component to the Menu simbling child component?

### App.js

```
class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            languages: ["FR", "DE", "GB"],
            currentLanguage: 'FR'
        };

        this.onLanguageChange = this.onLanguageChange.bind(this);
    }

    onLanguageChange = (currentLanguage) => {
        this.setState({
            currentLanguage: currentLanguage
        });
    }

    render() {
        return ( <
            div className = "App" >
            <
            LanguageSelector languages = {
                this.state.languages
            }
            currentLanguage = {
                this.state.currentLanguage
            }
            onLanguageChange = {
                this.onLanguageChange
            }
            /> <
            Menu size = {
                [1000, 500]
            }
            onLanguageChange = {
                this.onLanguageChange
            }
            currentLanguage = {
                this.state.currentLanguage
            }
            /> <
            /div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

### LanguageSelector.js

```
LanguageSelector extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            languages: this.props.languages,
            currentLanguage: this.props.currentLanguage
        };

        this.setCurrentLanguage = this.setCurrentLanguage.bind(this);
    }

    render() {
        return ( <
            div >
            <
            span className = "languageSelection" >
            <
            ReactFlagsSelect defaultCountry = "FR"
            searchable = {
                false
            }
            countries = {
                this.state.languages
            }
            onSelect = {
                this.setCurrentLanguage
            }
            ref = "countryCode" / >
            <
            /span> <
            /div>
        );
    }

    export default LanguageSelector;
```

Comment: You can use a store for that. Stores are made to share data between components. Take a look on redux

Comment: The perfect use case for context more info here: https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to pass the languageSelector change event up to the parent (App) and this should then rerender the menu - like so:

LanguageSelector:

```
<span className="languageSelection">
    <ReactFlagsSelect defaultCountry="FR" searchable={false} countries={this.state.languages} 
       onSelect={val => this.props.onLanguageChange(val)} ref="countryCode"/>
</span>
```

Note: you might need to check what onSelect returns and adjust accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I will try it. :)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [react-redux](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux). Otherwise, since you are controlling `currentLanguage` in the state of the parent component, passing the value as `props` will work perfectly fine. Don't reference the `currentLanguage` and `languages` props as a state in your `LanguageSelector` component, this can yield problems.

Try using the code below for your `LanguageSelector` component definition.

```
class LanguageSelector extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
        <div>
          <span className="languageSelection">
            <ReactFlagsSelect defaultCountry="FR" searchable={false} countries={this.props.languages} onSelect={this.props.onLanguageChange} ref="countryCode"/>
            </span>
        </div>
    );
  }
```

And then make sure you pass the `currentLanguage` variable from `App` `state` to the `Menu` component.

```
<Menu onLanguageChange = {this.onLanguageChange} 
    currentLanguage={this.state.currentLanguage}/>
```

And your code for the `Menu` component should then call `currentLanguage` from `props`.

```
class Menu extends Component { 
  constructor(props) { 
    super(props); 
  }

  onLanguageChange(language) { 
    this.props.onLanguageChange(language); 
  } 

  render() { 
    return <div className="menu"> 
        <h1>{this.props.currentLanguage}</h1> 
      </div>
  } 
}
```

Comment: Fixed incorrect `defaultCountry` reference from props in code example.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried it, but the result is the same. I have to dig more...

Comment: I've made the modification you suggested:
   <ReactFlagsSelect defaultCountry="FR" searchable={false} countries={this.props.languages} onSelect={this.props.onLanguageChange}/>
          
When I select a new language, the function onLanguageChange on the parent (App.js) is correctly called and the value correct (the new language selected).

onLanguageChange = (currentLanguage) => {
  console.log("App onLanguageChange: " + currentLanguage);
  this.setState({ currentLanguage: currentLanguage});
}

However, how can I say to the other child to use this received language?

<Menu ???/>

Comment: Make sure that you pass the `currentLanguage` from `App` to `Menu` component and reference `this.props.currentLanguage` from within the `Menu` component. Providing the code for `Menu` as well in your question, would help. :)

Comment: class Menu extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state =
    {
      currentLanguage: this.props.currentLanguage
    };
 
 componentWillReceiveProps(props) {
  this.setState({ currentLanguage: this.props.currentLanguage })
 }
 
 onLanguageChange(language) {
  this.props.onLanguageChange(language);
 }
 
 render() {
  return (<div>
            <div className="menu">
    <h1>{this.state.currentLanguage}</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
  }

Comment: I solved the problem. Solution: in Menu I was passing this.props.currentLanguage. I changed to this.state.currentLanguage and it seems to work now. I do not understand the reason why because for me it was obvious I should pass the prop and not the state. Thanks a lot for the help. Cheers!

Comment: If your question has been answered, please make sure to accept an answer (if any applicable) for further references or for people coming across this question in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I've made the modification suggested:

```
<ReactFlagsSelect defaultCountry="FR" searchable={false} countries={this.props.languages} onSelect={this.props.onLanguageChange}/>
```

When I select a new language, the function onLanguageChange on the parent (App.js) is correctly called and the value correct (the new language selected).

```
onLanguageChange = (currentLanguage) => {
  console.log("App onLanguageChange: " + currentLanguage);
  this.setState({ currentLanguage: currentLanguage});
}
```

However, how can I say to the other child to use this received language?

```
<Menu ???/>
```